# If I override ToString, do I need to override Equals and GetHashCode as well?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-3.0

I am sure if I override Equals, I need to override GetHashCode as well to make sure Dictionary, etc. data structures work as expected.

But if I just want to override ToString, do I still have to override Equals and GetHashCode methods?

Comment: See also [DebuggerDisplay attribute](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaredpar/archive/2011/03/18/debuggerdisplay-attribute-best-practices.aspx) - this is an alternative to overriding ToString (depending on what you want to do).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Overriding those three methods serve three different purposes:

1. ToString: Output representation of the object.
2. Equals: If two objects represent the same thing. It uses GetHashCode in its default implementation.
3. GetHashCode: Used for indexing of objects. Several advanced topics here including semi-uniqueness and distribution of hashvalues.

As you can see, 2 and 3 are related, but 1 is separate. Unless you implement Equals to simply test if the ToString of two objects are equals, which would most likely be a mistake. :)

So the short answer has already been given: You can override ToString without overriding the two other methods. It is quite normal to even overload the ToString method. See DateTime for an example: *[DateTime.ToString Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx)*

Comment: >>>>{Equals: If two objects represent the same thing. Uses GetHashCode in it's default implementation.}. I think it by default uses reference. Isnt it? And GetHasCode is for distribution of hash values. Isnt it?

Comment: Umm.. that sounds correct now that you say it. I might have spoken too soon on that account. I would have to look it up tbh. I guess I should go sleep. :) The main thing though is that Equals is not depending on ToString, so that's safe to change.

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't have to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`. They're not related to `ToString`

Answer (score 1):

No, you do not need to override Equals and GetHashCode if only overriding ToString().

Answer (score 1):

ToString is only meant to be a string representation of your object. Nothing more.

As you have stated though, were you to override Equals, it is best practice to override GetHashCode for HashTables. However the two operations are unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

You can override it just for a certain class, or do you mean override it on every class / object?

```
public class YourClass
{
    // Other stuff here...

    public override string ToString()
    {
        // Do whatever you want here instead, or return base.ToString(); for the default behavior
    }
}
```

But no, it’s not related to other methods and you can pick and choose what you want to override.