# Array is returning my Namespace and Type but not the Values that i put in

Tags: c#

im making .NET desktop app, im running into a problem. here is my class that i created with name,phone and salary properties:

```
namespace Employee
{
    internal class myEmployee
    {
      private string _name;
      private string _phone;
      private double _salary;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }

    public string Phone
    {
        get
        {
            return _phone;
        }
        set
        {
            _phone = value;
        }
    }
    public double Salary
    {
        get
        {
            return _salary;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value >= 0)
            {
                _salary = value;
            }
            else
            {
                _salary = 0;
            }


        }


    }

    public double AnnualSal
    {
        get { return _salary * 12; }
    }

    public myEmployee(string n, string p, double s)
    {

        
        Name = n;
        Phone = p;
        Salary = s;
    }

    public void RaisePay()
    {

        Salary *= 0.1;
    }




}
```

}

after that i initialized my array as follows:

using Employee;

```
   myEmployee[] emp = { new myEmployee("Bran","111-111-1111",2500),
                 new myEmployee("Patrick","222-222-2222",1000),
                 new myEmployee("Spongebob","333-333-3333",1500),
```

};

```
                 Console.WriteLine(emp[0]);
```

and when it runs it just displays my class name and type, not the items that i put in:

```
                 Employee.myEmployee
```

can someone help me in the right direction? I m thinking its cause of my naming convention but im not sure.

Comment: I think you'll want to create a ToString method for the classes that you want to print to the console. What you're seeing is the default behavior for C#.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I need to override ToString?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33166889/why-do-i-need-to-override-tostring)

Answer (score 1):

By default, `Console.Writeline(object)` (or in your case `Console.WriteLine(emp[0])` calls the `ToString()` method on Object or an overridden version of `ToString`. The default for `Object.ToString` is to output the type name (including namespace) as you've discovered.

While you can override ToString on your Employee type, that implementation would be used on all cases where you are trying to use ToString and doesn't allow customizations for different needs. Additionally, if you override ToString, the recommendation is to also override Equals and GetHashCode which doesn't make sense in your particular case.

As an alternative to overriding ToString, you might consider creating a specialized method to format the output:

```
public string PrintableString
{
   return $"Name={Name},Phone={Phone}";
}
```

or just format the value you want to display when you want to use it:

```cs
// Allocating a pointer here so that you don't index into the array multiple times.
var thisEmp = emp[0]; 
Console.WriteLine($"Name={thisEmp.Name},Phone={thisEmp.Phone}");
```

Comment: "the recommendation is to also override Equals and GetHashCode" where do you get that from? https://stackoverflow.com/a/8017784/14868997

Comment: That was a fxcop rule.

Comment: Can't find it, and I've checked old lists of rules https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/dd380629(v=vs.100)

Answer (score 0):

`myEmployee` is a complex type (a class with many properties).  By default, `.ToString` doesn't know what you want to show, so just outputs the name of the class.

If you want to show what properties are, you need to override ToString manually, and return the properties you are interested in (it doesn't have to be all of them).

```
class myEmployee
{
    public override string ToString()
       => $"Name={Name},Phone={Phone}";
}
```

Comment: Maybe your ToString method would better be shown as a traditional method (instead of the lambda), as the OP seems to be new to C#.

Comment: @Jason: Nit-pick, but this isn't a lambda expression. It's an *expression-bodied member*. It uses the same syntax `=>` as lambda expressions, but it's really not a lambda.

Comment: @JonSkeet, I thought it was a _statement lambda_. I wasn't familiar with the expression-bodied member terminology. Thanks for pointing that out.